# Bootstrap 5.0.2 breaks when I try to compile using Dart Sass

Tags: compiler-errors, bootstrap-5, dart-sass

I'm trying to change the primary color in bootstrap with SCSS. I followed all the steps installing Dart Sass and running it on a custom.scss, but when I try to do

```
@import "bootstrap" //with absolute path to bootstrap ofc
```

in custom.scss, it gives me the following error:

```
150 │   @return mix(rgba($foreground, 1), $background, opacity($foreground) * 100);
    │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    path\to\webapp\webroot\bootstrap-5.0.2\scss\_functions.scss 150:11            opaque()
    path\to\webapp\webroot\bootstrap-5.0.2\scss\mixins\_table-variants.scss 4:28  table-variant()
    path\to\webapp\webroot\bootstrap-5.0.2\scss\_tables.scss 134:3                @import
    path\to\webapp\webroot\bootstrap-5.0.2\scss\bootstrap.scss 22:9               @import
    path\to\webapp\webroot\scss\custom.scss 11:9                                  root stylesheet
```

I did not change anything to the uncompiled bootstrap scss. It seems to randomly throw errors because if I remove the line that is throwing the error, the error gets thrown on the command above it (on line 144). I don't know why it is breaking on a seemingly random command, and the error report doesn't give any feedback either.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to a previous version of dart-sass that is compatible with Bootstrap 5.0.2

```
npm uninstall -g sass
npm install -g sass@1.32.13
```